# When does a good link become toxic

Tags: google, backlinks, google-penguin-algorithm

It is my understanding and correct me if I'm wrong but with Google's penguin and daily **BACKLINK** algorithms it will do several checks before rewarding for the link. It will then regularly check that the link still works and still is **content relevant**.

I also understand or believe that Google can hit hard on external links when the page has been hit by spams. For example a page about cats with a kongzilla amount of spam links to various fake GUCCI and other spammy sites can hurt both the site that has these links, and the site that is receiving the link.

I appericate that my question may be hard to answer due to Google's lack of transpancy but none the less I'd like to see hear what people have heard regarding this situation.

The situation. You have a website and it has a '**MANY LEGIT COMMENT LINKS**' to your website. These websites at the time you received a link was well administrated and had good authority. Years on, you notice that the pages that you have a link on has over 1,000 outbound links to spammy sites.

With the situation information provided when does these links then become toxic? due to the fact the pages have bad neighbouring links and are non relevant thanks to the sheer number of comments that are diluting the page with non-sense.

What would be the correct actions to take:

- Message the site administrators and tell them to sort it out.... rofl.
- Message the site administrators to remove your link.
- Use the disavow tool
- Ignore it...

Comment: I know that Google is rather forgiving and understands crappy sites with crappy links to all of God's green earth and beyond- hence many of the SEO "me too" performance or keyword sites that link to your domain. 10,000 crappy links will have some value. But as you ask, where is the line where G decides that a link truly deserves a down-vote or moderator intervention? I am not sure and I am not sure anyone knows for sure...

Answer (score 1):

Isolated cases should not be a concern - if most links are good then the proverbial rotten apple will not spoil the barrel. You should indeed worry if your link systematically appears on such sites, so that the penguin may guess that you put in some work into getting them there.
At this point, disavow and manual removal are not mutually exclusive: you should disavow all dubious links - at least that is something under your control - then message sites' admins to also remove it and hope for the best.