# How to know which back-link passes good link juice?

Tags: pagerank, backlinks

Currently i am in the process of removing bad inbound links towards my website. Now apart from PR or domain related significance how i know that which inbound links are passes the good link juice for my site.

Is it there any qualitative approaches in this direction?

Comment: This is very similar to this question that currently has no answers: [What are objective criteria to assess if a backlink should be banned with Google's Disavow Tool?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86305/what-are-objective-criteria-to-assess-if-a-backlink-should-be-banned-with-google)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's not the similar with that one. The link which you are mentioned is about to bad back-links & how to use the Google Disavow tool. I am asking about the Link Juice which passes with rank signals towards the website.