# What should I do about spammy backlinks from suspect websites reported in Search Engine Console?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I have a lot of backlinks (it seems crawlers or something similar) in google console from domains like these :

```
https://gallos-de-pelea.info/
https://nationaldayofreconciliation.com/
https://beattynews.info/
https://fopp.info/
https://kazco.info/
https://thecrestsun.com/
https://4808.info/
...
```

Almost all sites with an error 500. What should I do regarding this? Ignore or use the disavow tool?

I have some fear of using it, since some people report a ranking drop.

Comment: I wrote an answer that explains so-called toxic links in reasonable detail. You may want to read https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/what-is-a-toxic-link/83835#83835 to better understand what a toxic link really is. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't noticed any problems from these links, you can safely ignore them.   Googlebot usually knows how to ignore poor quality links without you taking any action.   The fact that these pages now return 500 status means that Googlebot will not be able to see the links anymore either next time it crawls.

Other answers suggest using the disavow tool.   However, [Google says](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1088929651593039872) it is important never to use that tool unless you see a ranking drop that you suspect could be caused by the links.  Using the disavow tool without seeing ranking problems is much more likely to hurt your SEO than to help it.

Answer (score 0):

You should disavow any spammy or suspicious backlinks as keeping them may negatively affect your rankings (guilty by association).

Use tools like SEMRush to analyse toxic score of backlinks and the providing website, if it's below the threshold, Disavow without any delay.

If you are using SEMRush, then score of 60-100 – domain is Toxic, 45-59 – domain is Potentially Toxic.

Before getting rid of toxic backlinks, you need to review them.